# How to deal with EF6 dependency from the GAC

Tags: entity-framework-6

I need to update a set of platform level assemblies to use EF6.  These assemblies are installed in the GAC.  Is it safe to install EntityFramework.dll in the GAC with EF6?

Comment: Which assemblies do you mean? And why would you install EF in the GAC?

Comment: We have assemblies we have developed that are platform level assemblies.  The assemblies have been installed in the GAC for legacy reasons, such as COM objects that have dependencies on these assemblies.  Our assemblies that are in the GAC currently depend on System.Data.Entity.  When we change our dependency to EntityFramework.dll, what is the recommended solution?

Comment: The recommended solution is not to GAC EntityFramework.dll - it's supposed to be bin deployable.

Comment: Not being in a shared place breaks applications that depend on COM objects that depend on .NET assemblies that are in the GAC that currently depend on System.Data.Entity.dll.  I understand the recommendation is for bin deployment, but that leaves us stuck without being able to migrate forward until we have no more COM interfaces.  That's not likely to happen for a very long time.